# Finding all subtrees of nodes with a common second level relationship

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

I am working with bill of materials (BOM) and part data in a Neo4J database.

There are 3 types of nodes in my graph:

- `(ItemUsageInstance)` these are the elements of the bill of materials tree
- `(Item)` one exists for each unique item on the BOM tree
- `(Material)`

The relationships are:

- `(ItemUsageInstance)-[CHILD_OF]->(ItemUsageInstance)`
- `(ItemUsageInstance)-[INSTANCE_OF]->(Item)`
- `(Item)-[MADE_FROM]->(Material)`

The schema is pictured below:

[image: schema]

Here is a simplified picture of the data. (Diagram with nodes repositioned to enhance visibility):

[image]

What I would like to do is find subtrees of adjacent `ItemUsageInstance`s whose `Items`s are all made from the same `Material`s

The query I have so far is:

```
MATCH (m:Material)
WITH m AS m
MATCH (m)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(i1:Item)<-[]-(iui1:ItemUsageInstance)-[:CHILD_OF]->(iui2:ItemUsageInstance)-[]->(i2:Item)-[:MADE_FROM]->(m) RETURN iui1, i1, iui2, i2, m
```

However, this only returns one such subtree, the adjacent nodes in the middle of the graph that have a common `Material` of "M0002". Also, the rows of the results are separate entries, one for each parent-child pair in the subtree:

```
╒══════════════════════════╤══════════════════════╤══════════════════════════╤══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╕
│"iui1"                    │"i1"                  │"iui2"                    │"i2"                  │"m"                    │
╞══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│{"instance_id":"inst5002"}│{"part_number":"p003"}│{"instance_id":"inst7003"}│{"part_number":"p004"}│{"material_id":"M0002"}│
├──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│{"instance_id":"inst7002"}│{"part_number":"p003"}│{"instance_id":"inst7003"}│{"part_number":"p004"}│{"material_id":"M0002"}│
├──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│{"instance_id":"inst7001"}│{"part_number":"p002"}│{"instance_id":"inst7002"}│{"part_number":"p003"}│{"material_id":"M0002"}│
└──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

I was expecting a second subtree, which happens to also be a linked list, to be included. This second subtree consists of `ItemUsageInstances` inst7006, inst7007, inst7008 at the far right of the graph. For what it's worth, not only are these adjacent instances made from the same `Material`, they are all instances of the same `Item`.

I confirmed that every `ItemUsageInstance` node has an `[INSTANCE_OF]` relationship to an `Item` node:

```
MATCH (iui:ItemUsageInstance) WHERE NOT (iui)-[:INSTANCE_OF]->(:Item) RETURN iui
```

(returns 0 records).

Also confirmed that every `Item` node has a `[MADE_FROM]` relationship to a `Material` node:

```
MATCH (i:Item) WHERE NOT (i)-[:MADE_FROM]->(:Material) RETURN i
```

(returns 0 records).

Confirmed that `inst7008` is the only `ItemUsageInstance` without an outgoing `[CHILD_OF]` relationship.

```
MATCH (iui:ItemUsageInstance) WHERE NOT (iui)-[:CHILD_OF]->(:ItemUsageInstance) RETURN iui
```

(returns 1 record: `{"instance_id":"inst7008"}`)

`inst5000` and `inst7001` are the only `ItemUsageInstances` without an incoming `[CHILD_OF]` relationship

```
MATCH (iui:ItemUsageInstance) WHERE NOT (iui)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(:ItemUsageInstance) RETURN iui
```

(returns 2 records: `{"instance_id":"inst7001"}` and `{"instance_id":"inst5000"}`)

I'd like to collect/aggregate the results so that each row is a subtree. I saw [this example](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/09/26/neo4j-collecting-multiple-values-too-many-parameters-for-function-collect/) of how to `collect()` and got the array method to work. But it still has duplicate `ItemUsageInstance`s in it. (The "map of items" discussed there failed completely...)

Any insights as to why my query is only finding one subtree of adjacent item usage instances with the same material?

What is the best way to aggregate the results by subtree?

Comment: Added a new picture with better visibility of the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the roots is easy. `MATCH (root:ItemUsageInstance) WHERE NOT ()-[:CHILD_OF]->(root)`

And for the children, you can include the root by specifying a min distance of 0 (default is 1).

`MATCH p=(root)-[:CHILD_OF*0..25]->(ins), (m:Material)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-(ins)`

And then assuming only one item-material per instance, aggregate everything based on material (You can't aggregate in an aggregate, so use WITH to get the depth before collecting the depth with the node)

`WITH ins, SIZE(NODES(p)) as depth, m RETURN COLLECT({node:ins, depth:depth}) as instances, m as material`

---

So, all together

```
MATCH (root:ItemUsageInstance),
      p=(root)<-[:CHILD_OF*0..25]-(ins),
      (m:Material)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-(ins)
WHERE NOT ()<-[:CHILD_OF]-(root)
  AND NOT (m:Material)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-()<-[:CHILD_OF]-(ins)
MATCH p2=(ins)<-[:CHILD_OF*1..25]-(cins)
WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p2) WHERE (m)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-(n))
WITH ins, cins, SIZE(NODES(p2)) as depth, m ORDER BY depth ASC
RETURN ins as collection_head, ins+COLLECT(cins) as instances, m as material
```

Comment: Did you mean `MATCH (root:ItemUsageInstance),
      p=(root)-[:CHILD_OF*0..25]->(ins), 
      (m:Material)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-(ins)
WHERE NOT ()-[:CHILD_OF]->(root)
WITH ins, SIZE(NODES(p)) as depth, m
RETURN COLLECT({node:ins, depth:depth}) as instances, m as material` ? (Get a syntax error otherwise.) Looks like this doesn't quite do what I am looking for. This groups instances together by what material their items are made from, but does not take into consideration whether those instances are adjacent to one another.

Comment: Example: `inst5001` is grouped with `inst7006`, `inst7007`, and `inst7008` as part of a material `M0001`. While these are made from the same material, there are other instances in between `inst5001` and those other 3. So `inst7006`, `inst7007`, and `inst7008` make up a subtree with common material, but `inst5001` should be separate from those. Also, `inst7006`, `inst7007`, and `inst7008` occur twice in the instances list

Comment: @tony_tiger Yes to the first one, and I missed the grouping part. I updated the cypher to split it into 2 steps. Finding the start of the chain, and then picking up the rest of the chain.

Comment: this is grouping all into a `M0002` bucket: (sorted afterwards): `{'instance_id': 'inst5000'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst5001'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst5002'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7001'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7002'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7003'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7003'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7004'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7004'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7005'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7005'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7006'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7006'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7007'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7007'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7008'},
 {'instance_id': 'inst7008'}`

Comment: Looks like if an instance's `Item` is made from material 2, it gets included once. If an items is part of a common material subtree, it gets included a second time, even if that common material is not `M0002`

Comment: @tony_tiger Sorry, I had the wrong variable copied in the WHERE. ^^; Turns out WHERE ALL/SINGLE doesn't work unless you actually use the extracted variable X3

Comment: OK. The material grouping is working. But now non-adjacent instances are getting grouped together: `[{"instance_id":"inst7001"},{"instance_id":"inst5000"},{"instance_id": "inst7002"},{"instance_id":"inst7003"}]`. `inst5000` is not adjacent to the `{7003, 7002, 7001, 5002}` subtree of material M0002. Same with M0001: inst5001 is getting lumped in with 7006, 7007, 7008. For material M0003, inst7004 is getting grouped in twice

Comment: @tony_tiger right, need to keep the buckets distinct to be useful. Added the root instance to the return to act as the head of each group so that the COLLECT doesn't also merge the groups we separated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177126/discussion-between-tezra-and-tony-tiger).

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, you don't account for situations like the link between inst_5001 and inst_7001.  Inst_5001 doesn't have any links to any part usages, but your match pattern requires that both usages have such a link.  I think this is where you're going off track.  The inst_5002 tree you're finding because it happens to have a link to an usage as your pattern requires.

In terms of "aggregating by subtree", I would return the ID of the root of the tree (e.g. `id(iui1)` and then `count(*)` the rest, to show how many subtrees a given root participates in.

Comment: Hi, `inst5001` has an `[INSTANCE_OF]` relationship to `p001`. I confirmed that every `ItemUsageInstance` node has an `[INSTANCE_OF]` relationship to an `Item` node: `MATCH (iui:ItemUsageInstance) WHERE NOT (iui)-[:INSTANCE_OF]->(:Item) RETURN iui` (returns 0 records). Also confirmed that every `Item` node has a `[MADE_FROM]` relationship to a `Material` node: `MATCH (i:Item) WHERE NOT (i)-[:MADE_FROM]->(:Material) RETURN i` (returns 0 records). I wasn't necessarily expecting `inst5001` and `inst7001` to have any sort of link to each other (they are on separate branches of the tree).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my heavily edited query:

```
MATCH path = (cinst:ItemUsageInstance)-[:CHILD_OF*1..]->(pinst:ItemUsageInstance), (m:Material)<-[:MADE_FROM]-(:Item)<-[:INSTANCE_OF]-(pinst)
WHERE ID(cinst) <> ID(pinst) AND ALL (x in nodes(path) WHERE ((x)-[:INSTANCE_OF]->(:Item)-[:MADE_FROM]->(m)))
WITH nodes(path) as insts, m
UNWIND insts AS instance
WITH DISTINCT instance, m
RETURN collect(instance), m
```

It returns what I was expecting:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╕
│"collect(instance)"                                                                                          │"m"                    │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│[{"instance_id":"inst7002"},{"instance_id":"inst7003"},{"instance_id":"inst7001"},{"instance_id":"inst5002"}]│{"material_id":"M0002"}│
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│[{"instance_id":"inst7007"},{"instance_id":"inst7008"},{"instance_id":"inst7006"}]                           │{"material_id":"M0001"}│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

The one limitation is that it does not distinguish the root of the subtree from the children. Ideally the list of `{"instance_id"}` would be sorted by depth in the tree.